# directory error in dynamic php background

Tags: php, html, css, mysqli

I am trying to load a seperate image for each div by getting a directory from a database and inline styling

```
<div class="query">
    <?php
    if ($type == "category") {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM shopItems WHERE category = '" . $_GET['query'] ."'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
    $i = 0;
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $i = $i + 1;
        $url = '../img/'.$row['imgSRC'];
        if ($i % 2 != 0) {
            if ($i != 1) {
                echo '</div>';
            }
            echo '<div class="queryRow"><div class="item" style"background:url(' . $url . ') no-repeat; background-size:contain;">' . $row['productName'] . '</div>';
        } else {
            echo '<div class="item" style"background:url(' . $url . ') no-repeat; background-size:contain;">' . $row['productName'] . '</div>';
        }
    }
    echo "</div>";
    ?>
</div>
```

My problem is that when ever the page is loaded the slashes ("/") in the $url variable are replaced with spaces so the browser thinks an invalid url has been giver, how can i fix this?

Comment: this cannot be possible. I think urls already stored with spaces insted of slashes

Comment: Please show the value of the $url var and the final output in the div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

`style = "background:url(' . $url . ') no-repeat; background-size:contain;"`

instead of

`style"background:url(' . $url . ') no-repeat; background-size:contain;"`

```
echo '<div class="item" style = "background:url(' . $url . ') no-repeat; background-size:contain;">' . $row['productName'] . '</div>';
```

Comment: thanks, I didnt notice that, for some reason that was editing the $url string